# Repeating objects horizontally in crystal reports?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am developing  an application that generates ID cards. I am using C# and Crystal Reports 2012 to do this. When I generate the ID Cards the report comes out fine. The ID cards are repeated vertically. e.g

```
ID CARD 1    

ID CARD 2  

ID CARD 3
```

Now there is enough space left on the side of the page to generate 6 more ID cards on the same page. 
e.g

```
ID CARD 1  ID CARD 4  ID CARD 7  

ID CARD 2  ID CARD 5  ID CARD 6  

ID CARD 3  ID CARD 7  ID CARD 8
```

Can someone please tell me how to accomplish this ???

Answer (score 5):

Use the Detail's section "Format with Multiple Columns" feature.